# SQL Alchemy raises an exception that breaks the expected code flow (when breaking primary key uniqueness)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I have noticed a very weird behavior when running sqlachemy (version 1.4) with a context manager that handles the session. I am trying to validate catching the relevant exception when inserting a duplicate primary key. Instead, the flow of the program breaks (exit) and an "except" declaration is never reached.

Here is a simplified version of the code that reproduces that behavior:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

# Define the Engine and the Base
DB_PATH = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
engine = create_engine(DB_PATH, echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

# Define a basic table called 'labels'
class Label(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'labels'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

# Create all tables
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def session_scope(session_cls):
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = session_cls()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a label with id=1 and insert it to the DB
    label1 = Label(id=1)
    with session_scope(session_cls=Session) as session:
        session.add(label1)

    # create a another label with the same id and try to insert it also
    label2 = Label(id=1)
    with session_scope(session_cls=Session) as session:
        try:
            session.add(label2)
        except Exception as e:
            # Unfortunately, this code is never reached as I would expect....
            print("Cannot insert another row with existing id")
            print(e)
```

Instead of printing "Cannot insert another row with existing id", the code exits:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1771, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: labels.id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rbahumi/IdeaProjects/cafeteria/omri2.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(e)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/IdeaProjects/cafeteria/omri2.py", line 30, in session_scope
    raise e
  File "/Users/rbahumi/IdeaProjects/cafeteria/omri2.py", line 27, in session_scope
    session.commit()
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1428, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3298, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3438, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3398, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 242, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1094, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = connection._execute_20(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1583, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1452, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1814, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1995, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1771, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/rbahumi/venv/cafeteria/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: labels.id
[SQL: INSERT INTO labels (id) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: (1,)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

In order to debug it, I tried to replace the Session class with a "mock" that will raise the same exception:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

class MockSession(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Session:: __init__")

    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise IntegrityError("Session::add Exception", orig=Exception(), params={})

    def commit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Session:: commit")

    def rollback(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Session:: rollback")

    def close(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Session:: close")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a label with id=1 and insert it to the DB
    label1 = Label(id=1)
    with session_scope(session_cls=Session) as session:
        session.add(label1)

    # create a another label with the same id and try to insert it also
    label2 = Label(id=1)

    # This time, call with the MockSession
    with session_scope(session_cls=MockSession) as session:
        try:
            session.add(label2)
        except Exception as e:
            # This time, call with the MockSession reached this block as expected
            print("Cannot insert another row with existing id")
            print(e)
```

When I do that, the flow behaves as expected:

```
Session:: __init__
Cannot insert another row with existing id
(builtins.Exception) 
[SQL: Session::add Exception]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
Session:: commit
Session:: close
```

Any idea what can cause this sort of behavior?

Comment: The `IntegrityError` doesn't happen until the session is flushed, which happens during commit.  So you need to do `session.flush()` in your code, wrapped in a try / except.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by extracting the try/except clause outside the 'with' statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a label with id=1 and insert it to the DB
    label1 = Label(id=1)
    with session_scope(session_cls=Session) as session:
        session.add(label1)

    # create a another label with the same id and try to insert it also
    label2 = Label(id=1)
    try:
        with session_scope(session_cls=Session) as session:
            session.add(label2)

    except:
        print("We have reached this point :-)")
```

This is the correct way of implementing this, because the context manager's **exit**() function, which can also raise an exception, should also be inside the try/except clause.